# Meteor.user() only returns _id and username

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

After creating a users with the `accounts-password` and `accounts-ui` modules, when I call `Meteor.user()` in the console I don't get the full profile, only the `_id` and `username`, even though there is more on the document, like the `createdAt` record.

The same issue crops up if I use these templates:

```
<template name="user_list">
    <div class="user-list">
    <h1>Users</h1>
        <ul>
        {{#each allUsers}}
            {{> user_item}}
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="user_item">
    <li class="user-item">
        <p><b>{{username}}</b></p>
        <p>Created: {{createdAt}}</p>
    </li>
</template>
```

... backed by this helper:

```
Template.user_list.helpers({
  allUsers: function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({});
  }
});
```

In this case the user_list template iterates through users just fine, and shows the username, but the `createdAt` helper fails, even though if I go through `meteor mongo` the record is definitely there. I haven't removed autopublish; my setup is still fully open. Why can't I access the rest of the user records?

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user, by default only some properties are published to the client, you need to publish remaining properties using Metoer.publish and subscribe methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the accounts package only publishes the id, username and profile fields. To publish more, add this 'universal' publish to the server:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {

  if (this.userId != null) {
    return Meteor.users.find({
      _id: this.userId
    }, {
      fields: {
        'createdAt': 1,
      }
    });
  } else {
    return this.ready();
  }
});
```

Note: It returns `this.ready()` even if there's no user to ensure compatibility with the Spiderable package.

Comment: Why not just have `Meteor.publish(null, function() {return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, { fields: { 'fieldToPublish': 1 } }) });`. You can't have an `_id` as `null` on mongodb, so the conditional check is not required.

Comment: @Akshat, that would send one extra (unnecessary) query to the database, wouldn't it? However, publishes aren't reactive, so I don't think this will work that great.

Comment: @tarmes So far, I've read that published collections need to be subscribed to by the client. Is that necessary in this instance? If I call `return Meteor.user().createdAt;` I still get an undefined error. However, if I call the current user's info with `Meteor.user()`, I do now get the current user's `createdAt`.

Comment: You do normally need to subscribe to publications, but 'universal' publications (creating by passing 'null') are an exception. If Meteor.user() is now returning the information then there must be a problem with the Meteor.user().createdAt in your code.